# Get Data APDU command different tags and response format

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

As you may know, [Gloabal Platform Card Specification](http://globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp) defines a command named *Get Data* to retrieve some information from the smart card.

[*GlobalPlatformPro*](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) is one of the popular tools for communication with smart cards. When I *list* the installed applets on the card using this tool, I have the following output:

```
D:\3-TestTools\SmartCard>GP -list -d -v -i
//Useless Info Censored
ATR: 3B6800000073C84012009000
//Select APDU Command
A>> T=0 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0018+2) (48ms) 6F108408A000000003000000A5049F6501FF 9000

***** Card info:
A>> T=0 (4+0000) 80CA9F7F 00
A<< (0045+2) (65ms) 9F7F2A4250010C425102902610116000099A5A0AF9425211694253117E00000000000000000000000000000000 9000
Card CPLC:
ICFabricator: 4250
ICType: 010C
OperatingSystemID: 4251
OperatingSystemReleaseDate: 0290
OperatingSystemReleaseLevel: 2610
ICFabricationDate: 1160
ICSerialNumber: 00099A5A
ICBatchIdentifier: 0AF9
ICModuleFabricator: 4252
ICModulePackagingDate: 1169
ICCManufacturer: 4253
ICEmbeddingDate: 117E
ICPrePersonalizer: 0000
ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentDate: 0000
ICPrePersonalizationEquipmentID: 00000000
ICPersonalizer: 0000
ICPersonalizationDate: 0000
ICPersonalizationEquipmentID: 00000000

***** CARD DATA
A>> T=0 (4+0000) 80CA0066 00
A<< (0078+2) (95ms) 664C734A06072A864886FC6B01600C060A2A864886FC6B02020101630906072A864886FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B040215650B0609
2B8510864864020103660C060A2B060104012A026E0102 9000
GlobalPlatform card
Version: 2.1.1
TAG3: 1.2.840.114283.3
SCP version: SCP_02_15
TAG5: 1.3.656.840.100.2.1.3
TAG6: 1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.110.1.2

***** KEY INFO
A>> T=0 (4+0000) 80CA00E0 00
A<< (0020+2) (47ms) E012C00401018010C00402018010C00403018010 9000
VER:1 ID:1 TYPE:DES3 LEN:16
VER:1 ID:2 TYPE:DES3 LEN:16
VER:1 ID:3 TYPE:DES3 LEN:16

//Useless Info Censored
```

As you see above, the tool extracted `Card Info`, `Card Data` and `Key Info` from the card using following APDU commands:

- Card Info : `80 CA 9F 7F`
- Card Data : `80 CA 00 66`
- Key Info  : `80 CA 00 E0`

Questions:

1. Tags `E0` and `66` are mentioned in *Global Platform Card Specification*, but the tag `9F 7F` don't! Where is it specification?
2. As it is mentioned in the Global Platform Specification, the format of `Card Data` (Tag `66`) is defined in *ISO/IEC 7816 Part 6*. But in this document there is only a table as below:

[image]

As you see above, the contents of this table is really different from the output that I can see in GPP tool output. How I can interpret the outputs (Get Data APDU command responses)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(In context of Global Platform 2.2.1 and ISO/IEC 7816-6:2004)

- Tag **'E0'** (Key Information Template):

  - Defined in Global Platform (see section 11.3.3.1 and tables 11-27 and 11-28).
- Tag **'66'** (Card data):

  - Defined in ISO 7816-6 -- it may contain tag '73' called "Discretionary Data Objects" described as "Concatenation of data objects not defined in
    ISO/IEC 7816" (see Table 6).
  - Global Platform defines the contents of tag '73' within tag '66' (Card data) as "Card Recognition Data" (see section 7.4.1.3, appendix H.2 and Table H-1). This definition is in line with ISO 7816.
- Tag **'9F7F'** (CPLC / Card Production Life Cycle Data):

  - Defined in "Visa Integrated Circuit Card / Card Specification" which is not public (but might be found using google). The Open Platform 2.0.1 (predecessor of GP) defines that CPLC should be retrievable with the `GET DATA` command -- but it does not tell the particular tag.

Hope this makes some sense...good luck!