# Need to find unique id in the following smart cards: mifare , emv , calypso

Tags: smartcard, mifare, emv, calypso

I need to be able to read the unique id of the following card types: mifare , emv and calypso.

i m able to read the ATR of those cards , but could not find the command for receiving the unique id

```
Card card = terminal.connect("T=1");
CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
ATR r2 = channel.getCard().getATR();
byte atr[] = r2.getBytes();
```

Comment: At least a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39609445/1435475). I'll vote for close however, since the question seems too broad and I can't recognize a real attempt to solve it - the ATR is definitely far from unique.

Comment: have you checked this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609445/how-to-get-a-unique-smart-card-id?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the answer to all the specified cards is 0xFFCA000000 (UID)